# error while trying to register and get email to mailtrap.io

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I get this error when i try to register.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: users.username (SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "email", "password", "updated_at", "created_at") values (ddd, User@gmail.com, $2y$10$OAVW3PgwJ3tfqvCIGLOSM.mlOELN2sI72Um74Asn5vYhVqbg7x2SW, 2020-04-06 08:40:58, 2020-04-06 08:40:58))

User.php has this

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NewUserWelcomeMail());
```

why is that ? and my email in user_create table is

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) { 
    $table->id(); 
    $table->string('name'); 
    $table->string('email')->unique(); 
    $table->string('username')->unique(); 
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable(); 
    $table->string('password'); 
    $table->rememberToken(); 
    $table->timestamps();
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Your table has a column called `username` that doesn't allow `null` values and doesn't seem to have any default value. You need to assign that column a unique value when you insert a new record. if not, it will try and inset `null`, which it can't. So your issue is the `username` col, not the `email` col.

Comment: it worked perfectly before i changed the .env file

the mail part username and password from mailtrap.io

Comment: Well, the error you're getting is because you've omitted adding a value for the column `username`. And looking at how you create the user table, the field isn't nullable so you _must_ pass in a non null and unique value. If it "worked before" or not doesn't really matter. The error message is clear. It also doesn't make much sense adding users without any username.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the MailTrap, the issue is with the username column, Add value to username column while doing the insert in RegisterController.

Just make following code changes in `RegisterController.php` to add Username value in the `users` table.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'username' => $data['email'] // Or add logic to generate unique Username
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

This should fix the issue.